# How can I compile DSniff on Kali Linux?

Tags: compiling, kali-linux

For some reason, Dsniff isn't found on my Kali system. So I downloaded the DSniff tar.gz file and extracted it on my desktop using:

```
tar zxvf dsniff-2.3.tar.gz
cd dsniff-2.3
./configure && make && make install
```

I get the following error:

```
checking for Berkeley DB with 1.85 compatibility...configure: error: Berkeley DB with 1.85 compatibility not found.
```

How can I get Dsniff installed & working?

Answer (score 3):

No need to compile dsniff on a debian-like OS, simply run :

```
sudo apt-get install dsniff
```

Answer (score 2):

*Berkeley DB* is a common simple database used by a lot of things, so I am sure Kali should have it available.

At a glance it looks to me like Kali uses `apt`, so:

```
apt-cache search Berkeley
```

Should give you a list of a few dozen items.  Since you are building against it, you probably want the `libdb-dev` package.  Presumably this pulls in the executables as dependencies -- I believe that's one of the packages starting with 'db4' or 'db5'.